# In a url where Category Id is wrong It is showing wrong it is going to the page not found page

Tags: categories

In my one project  I am using old 2.8.4 version of word press. So If In url wrong category name is there then it is going to the page 404 page not found. But I want that still it should go to the archive page only.

In latest version of wordpress it is like that only. It is going to category page if i specify wrong category name then also.

So why it is not the case with old version what should do to go on the same page weather right category is there or wrong category is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really upgrade to the latest version. If you won't do that then simply copy your archives.php and paste it into the 404.php file.

Comment: I have Upgraded the version and it is working properly.